# Is there any command to pass a list of keys and get a list of hashes in Redis?

Tags: .net, redis, servicestack

The only way I know to get a list of hashes is to put `HGETALL key` command in a loop for given keys.
But, is there any single command to pass a list of keys and get a list of hashes in Redis?
This would be a very useful command for us.

I'm using [servicestack.redis](/questions/tagged/servicestack.redis) in `C#` for `Redis`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the HASH commands on, redis.io, e.g: http://redis.io/commands/hgetall

The docs on redis.io lists all the operations available in Redis which doesn't contain any native operation to get a list of Hashes. The alternative is to use a [Redis Transaction](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisTransactions) or [create a Redis Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisPipelineTests.cs) which batches all the commands in a [Redis Pipeline](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) which is an efficient way to send multiple operations that you don't need to block one-at-a-time on after sending each operation.

Finally you can [execute a LUA Script](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#efficient-scan-in-lua) which is the way you can create custom commands in Redis using LUA.